# Adding custom variable/stats to tqdm bar

Tags: python, python-3.x, tqdm

I am wondering if it possible to add a custom variable to the tqdm bar where the value sometimes updates with each iteration. For example:

```py
exception_count = 0
for _ in tqdm(range(1000), bar_format="Exceptions: counthere | Elapsed: {elapsed} |{rate_fmt}"):
    try:
        do_stuff()
    except Exception:
        exception_count += 1
```

I would like to add the `exception_count` variable somewhere in the `bar_format` parameter as a type of custom error counter.

Answer (score 3):

You can add additional stats to the progress bar using [`postfix`](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#description-and-additional-stats).

```py
import random
import time

from tqdm import tqdm


def do_stuff():
    time.sleep(0.01)
    if random.randint(0, 10) < 3:
        raise Exception()


exception_count = 0
with tqdm(
    bar_format="Exceptions: {postfix} | Elapsed: {elapsed} | {rate_fmt}",
    postfix=exception_count,
) as t:
    for _ in range(1000):
        try:
            do_stuff()
        except Exception:
            exception_count += 1
            t.postfix = exception_count
            t.update()
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this in the below way as documented in the [github repository of tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm)

```
pbar = tqdm(["a", "b", "c", "d"])
   for char in pbar:
      sleep(0.25)
      pbar.set_description("Processing %s" % char)
```

This will dynamically update the Progress bar description for every iteration.

For your problem, you will need to do the following:

```
exception_count = 0

pbar = tqdm(1000)
for _ in pbar:
    try:
       do_stuff()
       pbar.set_description(f"Exceptions: counthere | Elapsed: {elapsed} |{rate_fmt}")
    except Exception:
       exception_count += 1
```